# Coarse grained REST endpoint - extracting input

Tags: apex, rest-api

The following is my json input for an apex class where I am trying to insert records in a coarse -grained manner(inserting into tickets and payments in the same request- tickets have a reference to payments).

```
{ 
    "ticketPayments": [{
        "tickets": 
            {"External_TicketID__c":3,"Date_Time__c":"2015-09-13T22:30:00.000Z"},

        "payments": {"External_Pay__c":33,"TransactionDate__c":"2015-09-13T22:30:00.000Z","Amount__c":200.00}
    }, {
        "tickets": 
            {"External_TicketID__c":2,"Date_Time__c":"2015-09-13T22:30:00.000Z"}
        ,
        "payments": {"External_Pay__c":22,"TransactionDate__c":"2015-09-13T22:30:00.000Z","Amount__c":200.00}
    }]

}
```

The following is my apex class for inserting values only into tickets :

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/MultiTicket/*')
global with sharing class MultiTicketRestController{
global class RequestBody
 {
   global List<Ticket__c> tickets;
 }

@HttpPost      
global static List<Ticket__c>    createBulk(MultiTicketRestController.RequestBody req) {

       insert req.tickets; 
       return req.tickets;
   }

}
```

NOTE:  the input format of the apex class above is

```
{
"tickets": [{"External_TicketID__c" :"666","Date_Time__c": "2015-09-13T22:30:00.000Z","Payment__c":"2234"},{"External_TicketID__c" :"777","Date_Time__c": "2015-09-13T22:30:00.000Z","Payment__c":"2679"}]}
```

How can I transform this input(get External_Pay__c and Amount__c from the json input) so that i can insert tickets and payments in the same apex class in a coarse grained fashion(as below) using the above class.

```
req.tickets.Payments__r = New Payments__c(External_Pay__c= External_Pay__c,Amount__c=Amount__c);
insert req.tickets;
```

Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: did you look at https://www.adminbooster.com/tool/json2apex ?

Answer (score 1):

You could use RestRequest to get the raw JSON using the [requestBody](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_restrequest.htm#apex_System_RestRequest_requestBody) property.

Something like:

```
string rawJson = RestContext.request.requestBody.toString();
```

Then you could use JSON.deserializeuntyped to extract the required data.

---

**Update:** As Keith comments, Apex won't let you have member names ending in `__c`. That's reserved as a suffix for custom fields. You will need to use the options above of remove the __c from the JSON.

Or use a Json2Apex tool to create POAO objects to deserialise into. http://json2apex.herokuapp.com is one option to do this.

```
//
// Generated by JSON2Apex http://json2apex.herokuapp.com/
//

public class JSON2ApexTP {

    public class TicketPayments {
        public Tickets tickets;
        public Payments payments;
    }

    public List<TicketPayments> ticketPayments;

    public class Payments {
        public Integer External_Pay__c;
        public String TransactionDate__c;
        public Double Amount__c;
    }

    public class Tickets {
        public Integer External_TicketID__c;
        public String Date_Time__c;
    }


    public static JSON2ApexTP parse(String json) {
        return (JSON2ApexTP) System.JSON.deserialize(json, JSON2ApexTP.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: Think it'll have to be JSON.deserializeuntyped here as *__c e.g. External_Pay__c can't be used as field names.

Comment: @KeithC, Good point. Answer updated.